# Is there a chance to get a printer paper and ink status in NodeJS on Windows?

Tags: node.js, printing

I try to use Node.JS with the plugin node-printer (on Windows) to find out the status, if the paper or the ink is empty. Is that possible somehow? Because node-printer only gives me informations about jobs and says "PRINTING RETAINED" but not the real problem, that shows off in the printer screen. Like "Paper empty" or "Ink empty".

```
const printer = require("printer")
console.log(printer.getPrinter("CANON SELPHY CP1300"))

Output:

/*
{ name: 'Canon SELPHY CP1300',
  portName: 'USB001',
  driverName: 'Canon SELPHY CP1300',
  printProcessor: 'winprint',
  datatype: 'RAW',
  status: [],
  statusNumber: 0,
  attributes: [ 'DO-COMPLETE-FIRST', 'LOCAL' ],
  priority: 1,
  defaultPriority: 0,
  averagePPM: 0,
  jobs: [ { id: 7,
    name: 'Canon SELPHY CP1300',
    printerName: 'Canon SELPHY CP1300',
    user: 'Leon',
    format: 'NT EMF 1.008',
    priority: 1,
    size: 3161316,
    status: [ 'PRINTING', 'RETAINED' ],
    machineName: '\\\\DESKTOP-DUMDTFI',
    document: 'Testseite',
    notifyName: 'Leon',
    printProcessor: 'winprint',
    driverName: 'Canon SELPHY CP1300',
    position: 1,
    startTime: 0,
    untilTime: 0,
    totalPages: 1,
    time: 97482546,
    pagesPrinted: 0 } ] }
*/
```